# How does work the OpenMP "nonmonotonic:dynamic" schedule?

Tags: fortran, openmp

The two main OpenMP loop scheduling options are `static` and `dynamic`. The latter can be more efficient if the workloads are not balanced between the iterations, but less efficient in the case of balanced workloads (because the scheduling itself is more expensive).

The `nonmonotonic:dynamic` option that appeared in recent specifications is supposed to address this problem, by getting more or less the best of the two worlds: it starts like a static scheduling, but with a chunk size of 1 (by default, like the default chuck size of the `dynamic` option), and a thread that completes early all of its pre-attributed threads can "steal" the non-processed chunks from the other threads (at least this is my understanding).

However, when testing it, it's not really what happens. I have tested the following code (in Fortran, but it doesn'tt really matter) with gfortran 13, ifort 18, 19, and 21 (unfortunately I don't have access to more recent versions).

In short, it used 2 threads to execute 4 iterations. The first iteration is artificially delayed to see how the next iterations are attributed to the threads:

```
program foo
implicit none

    integer, parameter :: N=4
    integer :: i, t(N), o, order(N)
    real :: x(N)
    integer, external :: omp_get_thread_num

    call omp_set_num_threads(2)

    o = 0
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO SCHEDULE(static)
    do i = 1, N
        call loopcontent(i,o,order,x,t)
    end do
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
    call print_results("STATIC")

    o = 0
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO SCHEDULE(dynamic)
    do i = 1, N
        call loopcontent(i,o,order,x,t)
    end do
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
    call print_results("DYNAMIC")

    o = 0
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO SCHEDULE(nonmonotonic:dynamic)
    do i = 1, N
        call loopcontent(i,o,order,x,t)
    end do
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
    call print_results("NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC") 

contains 

    subroutine loopcontent(i,o,order,x,t)
        integer, intent(in) :: i
        integer, intent(inout) :: o, order(:), t(:)
        real, intent(inout) :: x(:)

        integer :: j

        !$OMP CRITICAL
        o = o+1
        order(i) = o
        !$OMP END CRITICAL
        x(i) = 0.0
        if (i == 1) then
            do j = 1, 10000000
                x(i) = cos(x(i))
            end do
        end if
        t(i) = omp_get_thread_num()
    end subroutine

    subroutine print_results(what)
        character(*), intent(in) :: what

        print*
        print "(A)", "==============================="
        print "(A)", what
        print "(A)", "    loop  thread  order"
        do i = 1, N
            print "(3I7,F10.3)", i, t(i), order(i), x(i)
        end do
    end subroutine

end
```

The 4 compilers behave the same (and as expected) or the `static` and `dynamic` cases, so I'm just pasting one output:

```
===============================
STATIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      0      4     0.000
      3      1      2     0.000
      4      1      3     0.000

===============================
DYNAMIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      1      2     0.000
      3      1      3     0.000
      4      1      4     0.000
```

Regarding the `nonmonotonic:dynamic` option, gfortran 13 and ifort 18/21 behave the same, and the execution order is not different from the `dynamic` option. Instead, I would expect the thread 1 to execute the iterations 2, 4, 3, in this order (the iteration 3 being "stolen" to the thread 0 once the iteration 2, 4 are completed):

```
===============================
NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      1      2     0.000
      3      1      3     0.000
      4      1      4     0.000
```

And ifort 19 behaves like with the `static` option, so still not as expected:

```
===============================
NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      0      4     0.000
      3      1      2     0.000
      4      1      3     0.000
```

Is my understanding of `nonmonotonic:dynamic` wrong, or is it an (non-)implementation issue (the compilers recognize the option, but just map it to `static` or `dynamic`)? Could someone test with a more recent ifx version?

---

### EDIT

Results obtained by Victor Eijkhout with the Intel ifx 23 compiler (after some modification to the code, likely as a workaround to a compiler bug; see answer below):

```
===============================
STATIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      0      4     0.000
      3      1      2     0.000
      4      1      3     0.000

===============================
DYNAMIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      1      4     0.000
      3      1      2     0.000
      4      1      3     0.000

===============================
NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      1      4     0.000
      3      1      2     0.000
      4      1      3     0.000
```

`dynamic` and `nonmonotonic:dynamic` are identical, but they differ from what is obtained with the other tested compilers. The [5.2 specification of OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-2.pdf) indeed says:

> If an ordering-modifier is not31
> specified, the effect is as if the monotonic modifier is specified if the kind argument is static
> or an ordered clause is specified on the construct; otherwise, the effect is as if the
> nonmonotonic modifier is specified

I though that `monotonic` was always the default, but it's not and my test should have tested `monotonic:dynamic` instead of simply `dynamic`.

Anyway, ifx 23 is the only one that shows a behavior that corresponds to a `nonmonotonic` intent, that is, a given thread can possibly process iterations in any order (instead of in increasing order). Still, the implementation is unclear:

- if the chunk size is 1, I would expect thread 1 to execute the iterations 2/4/3, in the that order. Instead, it executes iterations 3/4/2 (note that this is compatible with the specification, but why starting with the 3rd iteration, which is also the 3rd chunk?)
- if the chunk size is 2 (as in the `static case`), I would expect thread 1 to execute the iterations 3/4 (which belong to a single chunk)... and that's it. Instead it executes also the iteration 2 at the end, somehow stealing it from the thread 0, which started handling the first chunk (iterations 1/2).

The specification says very little about `nonmonotonic`, just:

> When the nonmonotonic ordering-modifier is
> specified then **chunks** may be assigned to threads in any order

My understanding is that whole chunks are attributed, and once a thread has been assigned a chunk, it always executes all the iterations of the chunk (i.e. iterations cannot be stolen by another thread). So, what ifx 23 does is still unclear.

Comment: For Intel 2023 I get zeros throughout the last column. If I remove host assocation (is that the term) by including `x` as explicit `print_results` parameter, I get the same as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have slightly modified the test code to better see the behaviors:

- n=8 iterations instead of 4 (still with nt=2 threads)
- as before, only the first has a significant (artificial) workload to ensure it's delayed and takes much more time than all other iterations, which basically do nothing
- testing explicitly the `monotonic:dynamic` case, as `nonmonotonic` is actually now the default for the `dynamic` scheduling
- testing the default chunk (which is 1 for the `dynamic` case), but also chunks of sizes 2 and 4

The tests are performed with gfortran 13 and Intel ifx 2024. For each test 4 columns are printed:

- The iteration number
- The thread number that executes the given iteration
- The "order" of the given iteration (e.g. "3" means that this iterations starts executing after 2 other iterations)
- a real number that is supposed to be 0.739 for the 1st iteration after some fake computations, and 0.000 for the other iterations.

The `static` and `monotonic:dynamic` schedule work as expected for both compilers:

- In the `static` schedule, the chunk size is n/nt=4 iterations, the thread 0 executes the iterations 1-4 and the thread 1 executes the iterations 5-8. Because the iteration 1 is much longer than the other ones, the iterations 2-4 are executed after all the other iterations
- In the `monotonic:dynamic` schedule, the chunk size is 1 iteration; the thread 0 takes the iteration 1 and spends the rest of the program execution on it, while the thread 1 takes the iterations 2-8 in that order.

For the `nonmonotonic:dynamic` schedule, the two compilers behave differently, though. gfortran 13 gives the same result than the `monotonic:dynamic` case: probably they didn't have time to develop this new schedule and have just mapped `nonmonotonic` to `monotonic`; I believe this is authorized by the OpenMP specification for `nonmonotonic`, which just opens up the possibility for a thread to iterate backwards, without mandating it.

So, the interesting case is the Intel compiler, which apparently implements the new schedule (and did it at least from ifort 2021, as I got the same results with it than with ifx 2024):

- **The default chunk size is still 1**, BUT in contrast to the monotonic case the thread 1 starts with the iteration 5 instead of 2. Then it executes the iterations 6, 7, 8. At this point the thread 0 is still occupied with iteration 1, and the thread 0 starts going backward by executing the iterations 4, 3, 2 in that order.
- What happens:

  - the initial distribution of the iterations is the same as the `static` schedule with the default chunk size, **regardless the chunk size** 1, 2, or 4 (note that the initial ditribution would be different with a chunk size that would not be a divider of the number of iterations, though).
  - **all** the iterations are pre-attributed from the beginning, in constrast to the usual `monotonic` case where there is no pre-attributation (each thread simply dynamically takes the next unprocessed chunk).
  - once a thread has finished with the iterations that were pre-distributed to it, it starts "stealing" the unprocessed iterations that were pre-attributed to the other threads
  - as shown by the cases with chunk sizes 2 and 4, a thread won't steal iterations from a chunk that another thread has started to process: **the distribution remains chunk based** (all the iterations of a sigle thread are processed by a single thread.

gfortran 13:

```
===============================
STATIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      0      6     0.000
      3      0      7     0.000
      4      0      8     0.000
      5      1      2     0.000
      6      1      3     0.000
      7      1      4     0.000
      8      1      5     0.000

===============================
MONOTONIC:DYNAMIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      1      1     0.739
      2      0      2     0.000
      3      0      3     0.000
      4      0      4     0.000
      5      0      5     0.000
      6      0      6     0.000
      7      0      7     0.000
      8      0      8     0.000

===============================
NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      1      1     0.739
      2      0      2     0.000
      3      0      3     0.000
      4      0      4     0.000
      5      0      5     0.000
      6      0      6     0.000
      7      0      7     0.000
      8      0      8     0.000

===============================
NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC,2
    loop  thread  order
      1      1      1     0.739
      2      1      8     0.000
      3      0      2     0.000
      4      0      3     0.000
      5      0      4     0.000
      6      0      5     0.000
      7      0      6     0.000
      8      0      7     0.000

===============================
NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC,4
    loop  thread  order
      1      1      1     0.739
      2      1      6     0.000
      3      1      7     0.000
      4      1      8     0.000
      5      0      2     0.000
      6      0      3     0.000
      7      0      4     0.000
      8      0      5     0.000
```

Intel ifx 2024

```
===============================
STATIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      0      6     0.000
      3      0      7     0.000
      4      0      8     0.000
      5      1      2     0.000
      6      1      3     0.000
      7      1      4     0.000
      8      1      5     0.000
 
===============================
MONOTONIC:DYNAMIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      1      1     0.739
      2      0      2     0.000
      3      0      3     0.000
      4      0      4     0.000
      5      0      5     0.000
      6      0      6     0.000
      7      0      7     0.000
      8      0      8     0.000
 
===============================
NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      1      8     0.000
      3      1      7     0.000
      4      1      6     0.000
      5      1      2     0.000
      6      1      3     0.000
      7      1      4     0.000
      8      1      5     0.000
 
===============================
NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC,2
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      0      8     0.000
      3      1      6     0.000
      4      1      7     0.000
      5      1      2     0.000
      6      1      3     0.000
      7      1      4     0.000
      8      1      5     0.000
 
===============================
NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC,4
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      0      6     0.000
      3      0      7     0.000
      4      0      8     0.000
      5      1      2     0.000
      6      1      3     0.000
      7      1      4     0.000
      8      1      5     0.000
```

Code:

```
program foo
implicit none

    integer, parameter :: N=8
    integer :: i, t(N), o, order(N)
    real :: x(N)
    integer, external :: omp_get_thread_num

    call omp_set_num_threads(2)

    o = 0
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO SCHEDULE(static)
    do i = 1, N
        call loopcontent(i,o,order,x,t)
    end do
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
    call print_results("STATIC",order,x,t)

    o = 0
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO SCHEDULE(monotonic:dynamic)
    do i = 1, N
        call loopcontent(i,o,order,x,t)
    end do
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
    call print_results("MONOTONIC:DYNAMIC",order,x,t)

    o = 0
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO SCHEDULE(nonmonotonic:dynamic)
    do i = 1, N
        call loopcontent(i,o,order,x,t)
    end do
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
    call print_results("NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC",order,x,t) 

    o = 0
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO SCHEDULE(nonmonotonic:dynamic,2)
    do i = 1, N
        call loopcontent(i,o,order,x,t)
    end do
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
    call print_results("NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC,2",order,x,t) 

    o = 0
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO SCHEDULE(nonmonotonic:dynamic,4)
    do i = 1, N
        call loopcontent(i,o,order,x,t)
    end do
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
    call print_results("NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC,4",order,x,t) 

contains 

    subroutine loopcontent(i,o,order,x,t)
        integer, intent(in) :: i
        integer, intent(inout) :: o, order(:), t(:)
        real, intent(inout) :: x(:)

        integer :: j

        !$OMP CRITICAL
        o = o+1
        order(i) = o
        !$OMP END CRITICAL
        x(i) = 0.0
        if (i == 1) then
            do j = 1, 10000000
                x(i) = cos(x(i))
            end do
        end if
        t(i) = omp_get_thread_num()
    end subroutine

    subroutine print_results(what,order,x,t)
        character(*), intent(in) :: what
         integer, intent(in) :: t(:), order(:)
         real, intent(in) :: x(:)

        print*
        print "(A)", "==============================="
        print "(A)", what
        print "(A)", "    loop  thread  order"
        do i = 1, N
            print "(3I7,F10.3)", i, t(i), order(i), x(i)
        end do
    end subroutine

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Intel23 gives zeros throughout columns 2/3/4. This seems to be a problem with host association (the mechanism of associating undeclared variables in a `CONTAIN`ed routine with the main program). If I pass `t,order,x` as arguments to `print_results` I get:

```
Compiling: ifx -g  -fopenmp  -O2 -g -qopt-report=5      -c nonmonotonic2.F90
with ifx=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.1.0/linux/bin/ifx
ifx: command line warning #10394: value of '5' for '-qopt-report' is greater than the accepted maximum; reverting to level '3'
Linking: ifx -o nonmonotonic2 nonmonotonic2.o         -fopenmp

===============================
STATIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      0      4     0.000
      3      1      2     0.000
      4      1      3     0.000

===============================
DYNAMIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      1      4     0.000
      3      1      2     0.000
      4      1      3     0.000

===============================
NONMONOTONIC:DYNAMIC
    loop  thread  order
      1      0      1     0.739
      2      1      4     0.000
      3      1      2     0.000
      4      1      3     0.000
```

Comment: Yes, it's "host association" (and it looks like an ifx 2023 bug). Your results differ from mines, and are still not as expected. Even the classical `dynamic` behaves strangely: the thread 1 executes the iterations 3,4,2 in that order, which is at least surprising (and I wonder if it's correct, as the latest specifications require `monotonic` to be the default, afaik)

Comment: Oh, I'm wrong... `monotonic` is the default for the `static` schedule, but `nonmonotonic` is the default for all other schedules (page 253 of https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-2.pdf). So it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to be aware of...

The default schedule (if none is specified) is `static`, however, that is **not** the same as `static(1)`. Indeed, (at least in the LLVM and Intel runtimes, which are the same :-)) it creates a static schedule which you cannot otherwise specify, since in any static schedule with a block-size the standard requires that when number of iterations is not divisible by the block-size there is only one small chunk, but that can lead to more load imbalance than is necessary, so the simple `static` schedule chooses a good block size and then allocates remaining iterations one each, so that there is an imbalance in the number of iterations executed per thread of only one iteration. (Where a blocksize is specified, that can lead to an imbalance of blocksize-1).

Although the standard states that the simple `dynamic` schedule can be treated as nonmonotonic, many (most?) OpenMP runtimes ignore that and simply continue to implement it as a monotonic schedule. The reasoning here being that most OpenMP users don't read the standard and don't realise that a `schedule(dynamic)` loop can be scheduled nonmonotonically. Therefore they may have code which would break with a nonmonotonic schedule. Since it used to work, it is hard for implementors to make the change as, although the user's code is incorrect, it used to work and now doesn't, so it's the compiler implementors fault.
For benchmarking you should therefore be explicit in all cases!

If you want more details on the runtime implementation of loop scheduling, read chapter 8 ("Scheduling Parallel Loops") in our book "[High Performance Parallel Runtimes](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110632729/html)", or read the associated code in the "Little OpenMP runtime": [LOMP](https://github.com/parallel-runtimes/lomp/blob/main/src/loops.cc).

Comment: I have chosen a number of iterations that is a multiple of the number of threads, just to avoid any ambiguity with unbalanced chunk sizes... Regarding whether `dynamic` is treated as `monotonic:dynamic` or `nonmonotonic:dynamic` your comment makes sense. Nonetheless according to the test from @VictorEijkhout it seems that the Intel 2023 compiler treat it as `nonmonotonic`. But my main interrogation right now is how the nonmonotonic scheduling really works in detail: can a thread "steal" individual iterations from another thread, or only a whole chunk?

Comment: At the level of the loop scheduler one is always dealing with chunks. So one has to steal an integral number of chunks (but that can be more than one}. See the code!

Comment: The presentation we made at OpenMPCon a few years ago has some performance data on the scheduling cost of  `nonmonotonic:dynamic` vs `monotonic:dynamic` it's at https://openmpcon.org/wp-content/uploads/2018_Session2_Cownie.pdf

Comment: I retain this sentence from your presentation: _"Gives an iteration distribution that is more like a blocked static one than a cyclic, dynamic one"_, which I think explains the behavior displayed by ifx 23.