How to make openmp schedule more orderly for checkpointing
I am trying to execute a large loop in C++ with #pragma omp parallel.
I need to keep track of range index values i which have been tested already (checkpointing) because the job will need to be resumed if it gets interrupted (killed). (Redoing of some of the work is fine.)  This code does good job on my intel based linux computer but on apple silicone openmp schedule is all over the place. See below. How it can be fixed? Or maybe there is a more advanced method of checkpointing in this context?
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <ostream>
#include <thread>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  omp_set_num_threads(3);
  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 100)
  for (int i = 0; i < 20000; ++i){
    int id=omp_get_thread_num();
    //using puts since it is thread safe
    if(!(i % 100)) puts((to_string(i)+": id:"+to_string(id)).c_str());
  //here instead of actual job, I am creating a tiny random delay
  mt19937_64 eng{random_device{}()};  //seed
  uniform_int_distribution<> dist{10, 100};
  this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{dist(eng)});
  }
return 0;
}

Linux with Intel:
0: id:2
100: id:1
200: id:0
300: id:1
400: id:0
500: id:2
....

Mac + M3 processor (with the mac openmp library and clang compiler):
0: id:0
6700: id:1
13400: id:2
100: id:0
6800: id:1
13500: id:2
200: id:0
6900: id:1

This schedule is useless for checkpointing. I am trying to avoid static schedule since it is not efficient.

It does not make sense to me in most case to do the check-pointing in the parallel loop, whatever the scheduling used. I think you should do some iterations, then do a barrier (implicit at the end of parallel loops) and then do the check-pointing. You can do the check-pointing in parallel asynchronously if this is a problem but this require at least to copy the check-pointed data before restarting a new loop so to avoid race-conditions.

Calling omp_set_num_threads is a bad practice and it should not be used. Prefer setting OMP_NUM_THREADS. You can also set the scheduling using environment variable (which is also a good idea).

"I am trying to avoid static schedule since it is not efficient" This is generally not true. Quite the opposite actually, especially on large scale servers or NUMA systems (including mainstream AMD CPUs for PCs). This is generally true on big-little CPUs (so new Intel PC CPUs and some Apple ones but not all of them). THis is why you should not set the scheduling in your program. Dynamic scheduling on NUMA system can be MUCH slower than static one.

In addition to excellent points already made, I think you may live in the misconception that screen output (or any sort of output) from a parallel region has anything to do with order of execution. Output goes through all sort of OS buffering.

The dynamic schedule has more overheads than the static schedule, and is interesting only in the case the workload is not well balanced between the iterations.

You should give the exact compiler versions you are using. It seems that the compiler+openmp library on your Mac uses the nonmonotonic variant of the dynamic schedule: this variant is relatively recent and not implemented yet in all openmp libraries (it was not in gcc 13, I don't know in gcc 14). On the Mac, try forcing the legacy monotonic variant with: schedule(monotonic:dynamic, 100)

Even with monotonic:dynamic printing the current iteration does not tell you that all lower iterations would be finished. The other threads are still working on their lower iteration chunks.

@Joachim That's correct, but I don't think that's the point of the OP.

@PierU: Your suggestion is indeed what I was looking for. If you make it into an answer I will accept it.

@Joachim: My code is indeed not entirely appropriate for checkpointing, but since the chunk size is fixed, I think I can implement true checkpointing with monotonic:dynamic schedule.

It seems that the compiler+openmp library on your Mac uses the nonmonotonic modifier of the dynamic schedule: this modifier is relatively recent (appeared in OpenMP 4.5) and not implemented yet in all openmp libraries (it was not in gcc 13, I don't know in gcc 14).
On the Mac, try forcing the legacy monotonic behavior with: schedule(monotonic:dynamic, 100)
The OpenMP 5.2 specification says:

In practice, with schedule(monotonic:dynamic,chunksize) schedule, each inactive thread is attributed the next unprocessed chunk of iterations, in order. With the schedule(nonmonotonic:dynamic,chunksize) schedule, the iterations are pre-assigned to the threads as if schedule(static) was used (regardless chunksize), and once a thread has finished its pre-assigned work, it is attributed any of the unprocessed chunks (that is, it "steals" the chunks that were initially attributed to the other threads). The nonmonotonic:dynamic schedule is meant to have at worst similar performances to the static schedule when the workload is balanced beetween the iterations, and as good performances as the legacy monotonic:dynamic schedule when when the workload is unbalanced.
See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77799465/14778592
